# Mark.js not highligting the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use mark.js for highlighting text in a specified container.

```
var searchKeyword = "ipsum";
$(".box").mark(searchKeyword, options);

<div class="box">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
</p>
</div>
```

Mark.Js: https://markjs.io/

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVMZyb

Comment: You had not included mark.js in your project, and options were not defined.. check here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wymGEP

Comment: Oh i must have not copied it properly, even though i did add the jquery cdn version https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVMZyb

Comment: options is not defined, remove the second parameter

Comment: I updated other codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mXxPQW

Answer (score 0):

Working example

```
var searchKeyword = "ipsum";
//$(".box").mark(searchKeyword, options);


$(".box").mark(searchKeyword, {
            "element": "span",
            "className": "highlight"
        });
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mXxPQW